# Google Maps API, My Icon and Default Icon Both Show Up

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, icons, maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ial1f.png)

Currently I'm using the Maps api and i've added my own icon, but for whatever reason the map shows both the default icon and my own, here is my quick code. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong for both icons to show up.

The main issue is that the default icon shows up above whatever icon I use and it shows a weird double icon.

Here is my code.

```
var myPin = {
url: "iconfinder_Beer_Mug_drink_3017884.png",
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
zIndex: 100
}


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
icon: myPin,
label: {
text: bName,
color: "#00546e",
fontSize: "18px",
fontWeight: "bold",
zIndex: 100
},
position: results[0].geometry.location
});
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : I read down the code and forgot I made a 2nd instance of the generate marker because I was planning on testing 2 different versions of it but neglected to comment one of them out. So it was always loading 2 of them.

All is fixed